# How to convert a html button into native script?

Tags: vue.js, nativescript, native

This is the html code, this button is used to filter food by name:
So the name of the food should be displayed as a button so that users can filter the option.

```
<button id="filterme" v-for="f in filterFood" 
@click="$chooseFilter(f)">Filter food by {{f}}</button>
```

This is the script code:

```
const app = new Vue({
el: "#app",
data: {
thisFood: [], //food array
newFood: {
  name: "",
  price: "",
  cuisine: ""
},

filterFood: ["null", "pizza", "chips", "rice", "chocolate", "salad"]

 methods() {
if (localStorage.getItem("thisFood")) {
   try {
     this.thisFood= JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("thisFood"));
   } catch (e) {
   localStorage.removeItem("newFood");
 }

   this.thisFood.push(this.newFood); //add new food
   this.newFood= {
   name: "",             
    price: "",             
    cuisine: "",          

  }


 }
},

chooseFilter(filter) {
  this.filter = filter;
},
```

I tried using a button it's not working.

```
<button text:"filterme" for =" f in filterFood" @tap="chooseFilter(f)"> 
Filter food by {{f}} </button>
```

Comment: Can you provide full code ! Current code is hard to find problem ..

Comment: Your binding on text attribute is not correct. Sharing clean code or possibly a Playground sample would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please take another look at the Vue documentation: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html

Maybe you're not sharing all your code, but the structure is way off.
Your `methods` function (which should be an object) is inside your `data` object.

Besides that you're missing parentheses .

Start with a valid structure and syntax:

```
const app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",

  data: {
    thisFood: [], //food array
    newFood: {
      name: "",
      price: "",
      cuisine: "",
    },

    filterFood: ["null", "pizza", "chips", "rice", "chocolate", "salad"]
  },

  methods: {
    chooseFilter(filter) {
      //
    }
  },
});
```